# How to use mongodb collections like constants with pymongo

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

I want to use my MongoDB collections easily with constants. Currently I do it this way in my collections.py:

```
def db_nk():
    from pymongo import MongoClient
    con_nk = MongoClient()
    return con_nk['nk']

class collections:
    col_user_news_makers = db_nk()['esh_user_news_makers']
    col_user_news_groups = db_nk()['esh_user_news_groups']
    col_user_news_sources = db_nk()['esh_user_news_sources']
```

I import collections.py in each file and use them like this:

```
collections.col_users_bulletin_instances.insert({...})
```

I think it's not a good way because there are always open connections to  Mongodb, but I don't know what is the best way. please guide me. thanks.
I have about 50 collections per project and there are 10 projects on a server simultaneously.

Comment: How many constants do you have to store?

Comment: @ReblochonMasque I have about 50 collections and I'm running 10 project like this on a server

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's nothing wrong with keeping *one* MongoClient open for the duration of your program, [as the PyMongo FAQ says](http://api.mongodb.com/python/current/faq.html#how-does-connection-pooling-work-in-pymongo). But creating a new MongoClient for each collection creates an unnecessarily large number of connections and threads. Additionally, accessing all the collections and storing them as attributes of a "collections" class seems to be code complexity that has no advantage.

Easier to just create everything at the module global scope:

```
from pymongo import MongoClient
con_nk = MongoClient()
db = con_nk.nk

col_user_news_makers = db['esh_user_news_makers']
col_user_news_groups = db['esh_user_news_groups']
col_user_news_sources = db['esh_user_news_sources']
```

Comment: You mean put this code in my publics.py and import it in the other modules?